# numpy array into matlab

Tags: python, matlab, file, numpy

Simple question: How do I save a NumPy array into a file that Matlab can easily read? I have found the scipy.io.savemat method but without any examples, I am having trouble figuring out how to use it. For instance, if I try this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio
theArray = np.array([0,1,2])
sio.savemat('theArray.mat', theArray)
```

Line 4 gives the error message "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'". How do I fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.io.savemat` wants a `dict`, not a numpy array:

```
sio.savemat('theArray.mat', {'theArray': theArray})
```

See [the official tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) for `scipy.io`.